# Почему не вызывается сервлет после ajax запроса?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

У меня есть небольшой веб-проект, собранный в `maven`, в нем имеется простейшее логин окно, которое с помощью `ajax` запроса обращается к сервлету. Проблема в том, что запрос не проходит, сервлет не вызывается. Однако если напрямую обратится к сервлету, то он работает как и следует(в не зависимости от данных запроса сервлет отправляет на сервер тестовую строку). Стало быть, причина в `ajax` запросе.

Код окна

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Log In</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#login-button").click(function(){
                var userPassword = $("input#userPassword").val();
                var userLogin = $("input#userLogin").val();
                var dataString = "log_in " + userLogin + " " + userPassword;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/login",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert("Successful request");
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("Unsuccessful request");
                    },
                    dataType: "text"
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="login-form">
        <h1>Login Form</h1>
        <input id="userLogin" type="text" name="user-login" placeholder="Enter login"/>
        <input id="userPassword" type="password" name="user-password" placeholder="Enter password"/>
        <input id="login-button" type="submit" value="Log in"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Сервлет, написан на `java`, таким образом зарегестрирован в `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Может быть дело в url: "/login"? ContextPath вашего приложения какой ? Чаще всего url должен быть типа такого /app-name/login, где app-name - это и есть context path. Возможно еще и адрес сервера длжен быть. http//server:port/contextPath/login. $.ajax в лучшем случае пытается пробиться на http//server:port/login

Comment: В этом и было дело, следует указывать полный адрес, включая адрес сервера - `http//server:port/contextPath/login`

Comment: Можете оформить ответ на свой вопрос. Странно только что требуется ещё и адрес сервера. Я полагал, что jquery  придерживается правила, когда к запросу автоматически добавляется базовый адрес (в нашем случае http//server:port) Тогда в JSF например было бы очень просто сформировать URL программно, избегая жесткого кодирования.url = "#{request.contextPath}/login". С сервером будет немного сложней.

Answer (score 1):

Причина в неверном `url`, в нем необходимо указать сервер, порт, contextPath приложения, то есть он примет следующий вид - `url :"http//server:port/contextPath/login"`